Are etymology questions on topic?
As the title, should we allow questions about etymology? For example "Qual è l'origine della parola Pasqua?"

Sorry for the nit-picking, but since we are in a site about Italian language: “qual è”, not “qual'è”.

No problem, however it is good practice on our network to simply go on and edit, there's no need to ask me to fix when you can do it yourself :-)

Ok, thanks! But perhaps the remark in itself might be of some use, since it is a quite frequent mistake. (Plus, I can't edit other people's text; perhaps my reputation here is insufficient.)

@DaG Anybody can edit any normal post on any SE site (at worst your edit will need approval), so go ahead and change! The comment can/should be left as a comment on the change.

I see; perhaps is it different on Meta? I see “edit” in gray...

@DaG try to click it :)

Thanks for the quite useful tip, but for some reason I see “close” and “flag” as black, clickable links, while if I hover on “edit”, “Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites” appears.

Ops. I should have known better :-)

Since we are being nit-picky, it should be è in place of e'. (You are probably using a US keyboard layout and I understand the pain of writing accents)

@GabrielePetronella deadkeys might help

I believe so.
Etymology can help in understanding the proper use of a term, so they look indeed related to the main topic of this site.

Io direi proprio di sì! L'etimologia è molto interessante per qualunque lingua, perché escluderla?
